# How to select a retrieved data

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently working on a library project.In it I use PHP to search for a book,retrieve book data from a database and show it on a table.Following is the code.

```js
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "vidunena";

$search = "";

if(isset($_POST['search']))
 {
  $search = $_POST["search"];
 }

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql=" 
SELECT DISTINCT b.isbn
             , b.bname
             , b.bauthor
             , b.btype 
          FROM books b
         WHERE CONCAT(isbn, '', bname, '', bauthor, '', btype) 
          LIKE '%" . $search . "%' 
";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
 {
?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['isbn']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['bname']?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['bauthor']?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['btype']?></td>
        </tr>
<?php  
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

And this is the output.

[image]

The code works perfectly fine.But I have no way to select a book from the shown results in the table in order to reserve the book.How do I make it possible?

Comment: What part of that exactly is giving you trouble?  We're not going to write a whole reservation system for you.

Comment: Actually,I need to select one of the books shown in the table in order to reserve it. So i need a way to select it.

Comment: Okay, and _how_ do you want to select it? Do you want the page to just have one dropdown where you select a book? Or do you want them all still listed out like you have above, but having (for example) the name clickable?  And for either of those, _what have you tried_ to accomplish that goal?  You need to show some attempt to do what you want.

Comment: I tried the second option by trying to make it a link using <a> tag. But it did not work.

Comment: Your code above does not reflect that.  Show what you tried.  Explain the desired result.  Explain the actual result.  Explain what you have done to debug it.

Comment: How come the result set isn't 'distinct'?

Comment: @Strawberry - It is: `'J.K' != 'J.K.' `

Comment: @paulspiegel my eyes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with JS if you want. Just add onclick event to every record.

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "vidunena";

$search = "";

if(isset($_POST['search']))
    {
        $search = $_POST["search"];
    }

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql=" SELECT DISTINCT books.isbn,books.bname,books.bauthor,books.btype FROM books WHERE CONCAT(isbn, '', bname, '', bauthor, '', btype) LIKE '%" . $search . "%' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
?>
        <tr onclick="select(this)">
            <td><?php echo $row['isbn']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['bname']?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['bauthor']?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['btype']?></td>
        </tr>
<?php       
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

**JS:**

```
function select(el) {
  var isbn = el.querySelector(".content a:nth-child(1)");
  var name = el.querySelector(".content a:nth-child(2)");
  //... and author and type if you want
  //I don´t know what exactly you meant with reserve so there you can add it...
  reserve(isbn);
}
```

If reservation cannot be done with JS, then I suggest to make it as links to another PHP sccript.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found my own answer.

```
<td>
<?php
  echo('<a href="my_page.php?action&serial='.$row['bname'].'">'.$row['bname'].'</a>');
?>
</td>
```

By using an anchor I was able to make the book names clickable. Thanks for helping!